# Use Case label in it's statement

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

Is it possible use case values in it's statement? In code:

```
switch (a) {
    case 0: {
       ...
       break;
    };
    case 1: case 2: {
       // is it possible use case value here (1 or 2) ?
       break;
    }
}
```

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`case` value indicates to the initial operand value of `switch` condition, i.e. `a` (in your case):

```
switch (a) {
    case 0: {
       ...
       break;
    };
    case 1: case 2: {
       // use 'a' variable
       break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible but your switch statement syntax is wrong, see this example:

```
var a = 1;

switch (a) {
  case 0:
      // do stuff
      break;
  case 1:
  case 2:
      alert(a); // alerts "1"
      break;
  default:
      // do default stuff
      break;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/opddf72u/)